# How to remove all html tags from downloaded page

Tags: python

I have downloaded a page using urlopen. How do I remove all html tags from it? Is there any regexp to replace all <*> tags?

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A very simple regexp would be :

```
import re
notag = re.sub("<.*?>", " ", html)
```

The drawback of this solution is that it doesn't remove javascript or css, but only tags.

Comment: That one will fail on you if you have non-escaped '<' and '>' characters outside or inside of the actual tags. If that is not an issue, you can use a regexp. If not, you will need to use an actual html/xml parser.

Comment: -1: Ill-advised, brittle solution.  It will be hard to debug the page with one extra "<" or ">" that breaks this.

Comment: It's simple and efficient, a great of cleaning data simply, I personnaly use it daily. When it comes to a more complicated problems, I then use BeautifulSoup, but please : let's keep simple problems _simples_. The case you're evoking here will be rare, if not unexistant. Taking it into account would be necessary ONLY if you need ALL your potential data, and you need it absolutely clean.

Comment: There are only about a thousand ways this can fail, and absolutely will for real web pages.

Answer (score 40):

I can also recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is an easy to use html parser. There you would do something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
all_text = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

This way you get all the text from a html document.

Comment: This requires an external library which is not always a solution to meet the needs of certain folk where they wish to distribute the script.

Comment: i would add the utf-8 encoding as well: `all_text = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True)).encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 11):

There's a great python library called [bleach](https://pypi.org/project/bleach/).  This call below will remove all html tags, leaving everything else (but not removing the content inside tags that are not visible).

```
bleach.clean(thestring, tags=[], attributes={}, styles=[], strip=True)
```

Comment: If there's single `>`, it will get escaped to `&gt;`. Not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re

def remove_html_tags(data):
  p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
  return p.sub('', data)
```

Comment: I agree. This code did exactly what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you need HTML parsing, Python has [a module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) for you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) which is supposed to make a readable text equivalent from an HTML source (programatically with Python or as a command-line tool).
Thus I may extrapolate your needs from your question...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to filter out Html tags from data. you can use Regex or remove_tags from w3lib which is in-built in python.

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
data_to_remove = '<p>hello\t\t, \tworld\n</p>'
print remove_tags(data_to_remove)`
```

**OUTPUT:** hello-world

*Note: remove_tags accept string object. you can pass remove_tags(str(data_to_remove))*