# Remove all XML tags, only keep the text between the tags

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML (an XML-stylesheet, actually).
With Python, I would like to remove ALL the tags from it and only keep the text between the tags.

What is the simplest solution for this ?
I saw a similar question here:
[How to remove all html tags from downloaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351485/python-how-to-remove-all-html-tags-from-downloaded-page)

But for some reason this doesn't seem to work in this case.
Please note that I do not wish to keep the text delimited by quotes within the tags - I really want to remove EVERYTHING that starts with a "<" and ends with a ">".

Comment: Got a sample of the file/doc you want to strip stuff from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`xml.parsers.expat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html#module-xml.parsers.expat):

```py
from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate

def char_data(data):
    if data.strip(): # skip empty text if you want
        print data

parser = ParserCreate()
parser.CharacterDataHandler = char_data
parser.Parse(doc,True)
```

Or [`xml.sax`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax):

```py
from xml.sax import make_parser, handler

class extract_text(handler.ContentHandler):
    def characters(self,data):
        if data.strip():
            print data

parser = make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(extract_text())
parser.feed(doc)
```

If it's not a well-formed XML, you could also try the [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html):

```py
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class extract_text(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self,data):
        if data.strip():
            print data

parser = extract_text()
parser.feed(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you - seems like a nice solution.
However, this chokes at the first occurrence of the character '&' in the text (not inside a tag), with the following error:

xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 701, column 778

Comment: @calvintiger the HTMLParser is less strict and can handle the `&`. Give it a try, maybe it works for your (malformed) XML document. Alternatively you could try to fix the XML before passing it to the strict parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (or the faster API equivalent [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)), then use the `etree.totext(tree, method='text')` function to serialize the tree back to just the text content:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> doc='''\
... <?xml-stylesheet href="common.css"?>
... <?xml-stylesheet href="modern.css"
...   title="Modern" media="screen"
...   type="text/css"?>
... <?xml-stylesheet href="classic.css"
...   alternate="yes" title="Classic"
...   media="screen, print" type="text/css"?>
... <ARTICLE>
...   <HEADLINE>Fredrick the Great meets
...     Bach</HEADLINE>
...   <AUTHOR>Johann Nikolaus Forkel</AUTHOR>
...   <PARA>
...     One evening, just as he was
...     getting his
...     <INSTRUMENT>flute</INSTRUMENT>
...     ready and his musicians were
...     assembled, an officer brought him a
...     list of the strangers who had arrived.
...   </PARA>
... </ARTICLE>
... '''
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(doc)
>>> ET.tostring(tree, method='text')
'\n  Fredrick the Great meets\n    Bach\n  Johann Nikolaus Forkel\n  \n    One evening, just as he was\n    getting his\n    flute\n    ready and his musicians were\n    assembled, an officer brought him a\n    list of the strangers who had arrived.\n  \n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lxml can be problematic, you can do the exact thing Martijn Pieters said with ElementTree or C version cElementTree which is in standard library.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> doc='''
...  <?xml-stylesheet href="common.css"?>
...  <?xml-stylesheet href="modern.css"
...    title="Modern" media="screen"
...    type="text/css"?>
...  <?xml-stylesheet href="classic.css"
...    alternate="yes" title="Classic"
...    media="screen, print" type="text/css"?>
...  <ARTICLE>
...    <HEADLINE>Fredrick the Great meets
...      Bach</HEADLINE>
...    <AUTHOR>Johann Nikolaus Forkel</AUTHOR>
...    <PARA>
...      One evening, just as he was
...      getting his
...      <INSTRUMENT>flute</INSTRUMENT>
...      ready and his musicians were
...      assembled, an officer brought him a
...      list of the strangers who had arrived.
...    </PARA>
...  </ARTICLE>
...  '''

>>> xml = ElementTree.fromstring(doc)
>>> xml
<Element 'ARTICLE' at 0x9295e6c>
>>> ElementTree.tostring(xml,method='text')
'\n   Fredrick the Great meets\n     Bach\n   Johann Nikolaus Forkel\n   \n     One evening, just as he was\n     getting his\n     flute\n     ready and his musicians were\n     assembled, an officer brought him a\n     li
st of the strangers who had arrived.\n   \n '
```

Note that cElementTree is faster, it is in standard library but i think it has some problem with UTF8, so if you need utf8 use "ElementTree"