# How to replace a tag with space Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Suppose i have

```
text = """ <a href = 'http://www.crummy.com/software'>Hello There</a>"""
```

I want to replace the a hrefs and /a with just put a space (" "). In its place. BTW its a BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup Class. So normal .replace wouldn't work.

I want text to be just

```
""" Hello There """
```

Notice the space after and before "Hello There".

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`replaceWith()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) (or [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
 <body>
  <a href = 'http://www.crummy.com/software'>Hello There</a>
 </body>
</html>
""")

for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a.replaceWith(" %s " % a.string)

print soup
```

prints:

```
<html><body>
 Hello There 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `.replace_with()` and the `.text` attribute:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> text = """ <a href = 'http://www.crummy.com/software'>Hello There</a>"""
>>> soup = BS(text)
>>> mytag = soup.find('a')
>>> mytag.replace_with(mytag.text + ' ')
<a href="http://www.crummy.com/software">Hello There</a>
>>> print soup
 Hello There
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 import re
 notag = re.sub("<.*?>", " ", html)
 >>> text = """ <a href = 'http://www.crummy.com/software'>Hello There</a>"""
 >>> notag = re.sub("<.*?>", " ", text)
 >>> notag
 '  Hello There '
```

See this anwser : [How to remove all html tags from downloaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351485/python-how-to-remove-all-html-tags-from-downloaded-page)